# Exception when accessing active directory in asp.net using the default application pool identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am getting an exception when trying to access active directory using the default application pool identity [IIS APPPOOL\{application pool name}].

the exception I get is

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: An operations error occurred.

when attempting

```
var userFound = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName)
```

This same code works with when using Network Service as the application pool identity, but I would like to know how to get this working using the default application pool identity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the default identity doesn't have permission to access AD.  You could try using a domain account for the application pool identity, or specify a username and password when constructing your PrincipalContext.

Comment: Is there any way I can allow the default application pool identity to have access to AD(by setting permissions or some other way)?

Comment: @user2384219 - Maybe it's possible: the fact that Network Service can access AD suggests it ought to be.  But I don't know how to do it.